# How do I delete an image with cloud functions with download url?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I want to delete an image. All I have is the download url.
In flutter i am able to get file path from download url and use that path to delete the file in cloud storage.

Is that possible to get the file path from download url and use that path to delete the image from cloud functions?

or is there any better/ faster way / more efficient way to delete an image from cloud storage only with the download url

Comment: The best thing to do, of course, is store the path in Cloud Storage in your database in the first place.  But it sounds like that wasn't part of the design.

Comment: yup it was not a part of the design. what do i do?

Comment: there should be a function to get path from download url. Is there?

Comment: In the client SDKs, yes. No server SDK has this.

Comment: I think the feature to get storage location from url should be implemented. Its very much used in client sdk and should also be a feature in backend

Comment: You are always free to file a feature request. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage object URL has the following parts:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/[bucket_name]/[path/and/the/object/name*]?[autentication_if_needed]
```

*Path in Cloud Storage is "virtual", in fact it is an integral part of the object name/identification. Cloud Console and gsutil simulates folders for the user interface output.

There are several [methods to delete object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects#storage-delete-object-python):

1. From the Cloud Console
2. Using Cloud SDK command: gsutil rm gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]
3. Using Client Libraries, for example with python:

> ```
>  def delete_blob(bucket_name, blob_name):
>         """Deletes a blob from the bucket."""
>         storage_client = storage.Client()
>         bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
>         blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
>         blob.delete()
>         print('Blob {} deleted.'.format(blob_name))`
> ```

Please keep in mind, that you need proper [permissions to delete the object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) for the user/service account used to perform the operation.

Comment: I believe the question is asking about download URLs that are generated by Firebase client libraries, which is a different thing than what you're talking about here.